# Почему не работает подключение SVG файла c помощью img?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

```html
<svg height='100' width='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <style>
    .polylogobox {
      fill: #ef402a;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #ef402a;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover + text {
      fill: #ef402a;
    }
    .logoletter {
      font-size: 26px;
      fill: white;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    .logoname {
      font-size: 32px;
      fill: white;
    }
  </style>
  <polygon class='polylogobox' points='22,0 44,0 48,6 72,6 72,46 22,46' />
  <text class='logoletter' x='38' y='36'>E</text>
  <text class='logoname' x='6' y='94'>Expire</text>
</svg>
```

Сделал такой логотип с помощью `SVG`

Сохранил в формате `.svg`, а потом попытался добавить на страницу с помощью тега `img` таким образом:

```
<img src="img/logo.svg" alt="asd">
```

По какой-то причине логотип не хочет добавляться, путь `100%` правильный, имя файла тоже `100%` правильное.
 Если же добавлять тот же самый код на страницу без сохранения в `SVG` файл, то все работает.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Всё дело в том, что вы попали в ловушку разницы работы парсеров `Html` и `xml`
Первый не выдает сообщение об ошибке отсутствия указания `Namespaces`. А файл `svg` не будет работать без указания `Namespaces`

Для проверки попробуйте сохранить код вашего лого в файл с расширением *.svg.

Код не будет выполнен и парсер `xml` выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

- Поэтому всегда добавляйте в шапке svg `Namespaces`

`<svg  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height='100' width='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>`

- Теперь вызов svg файла будет работать:

  `<img src="img/logo.svg" width="200" height="200"  alt="image description">`
- Указывая ширину и высоту можно дополнительно регулировать размер
  лого.

*Следующий ваш вопрос будет почему не работает анимация при наведении.*

Потому что вы вызываете svg файл через `<img src...` В этом случае ваш файл трактуется как картинка и поэтому анимации не будет выполняться - `( transition: .2s;)`

Чтобы выполнялась анимация, нужно подключать файл с помощью команды `<object>`

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/logo.svg" width="200" height="200">
 </object>`

Более подробно о других способах подключения файлов svg [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

Comment: Саша как всегда ... отличный ответ ... развёрнутый и подробный ! плюсик от меня